# Server not exiting after using fork() call in socket

Tags: c, sockets, fork

Before adding fork(), the code below worked fine but after calling fork() call, the server is running infinitely. I want the server to exit after serving a specific number of clients and want the server to terminate thereafter.

```
for(count = 0; count < 2; count++)
{
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if(fork() ==  0)
    {
        printf("from Server\n");
    }
    close(client_socket);
}

    close(server_socket);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "running infinitely"? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the for loop is not getting terminated.

Comment: The for loop is getting terminated, not sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you want to serve specific number of  client then terminate, try:

```
#define MAX_CLIENTS 3
for(count = 0; count < MAX_CLIENTS; count++)
{

    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if(fork() !=  0)
    {
    /*Thats parent it will go back listening*/
        printf("from Server\n");
    }
    else
    {
    /*Thats child it will Serv the client and terminate*/
    close(client_socket);
    exit(0);
    }
}

    close(server_socket);
```